# Mesh Scale Huge for .stl file

Tags: gazebo, urdf

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello, having a problem where the meshes which i'm importing to my URDF file are absolutely huge. The dimensions are correct in solidworks (around 400mm cube). I tried changing the units of the part back to meters as i was working in mm and this had no effect. Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8294/mesh-scale-huge-for-.stl-file/) by [adam896](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1108/adam896/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-03-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2015-03-19**:
It would help if you're able to share your STL and URDF files. You can just update the question.

**Comment by [adam896](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1108/adam896/) on 2015-03-23**:
I dont really know what was causing this, maybe the fact that the solidworks model was developed in mm rather than m, i ended up just using a scaling tag and setting the three parameters to 0.001 and it imported fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It [seems](https://wps3dprinter.wordpress.com/designing/stl-units/) that there isn't a way to specify units in STL files. So whatever unit you use will be treated as meters by Gazebo. That's why your `400 mm` cube came out as a `400 m` cube.

Your solution seems to be the easiest one, to specify a scaling factor for the mesh on [SDF](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.5&elem=geometry#mesh_scale), from `mm` to `m` for example:

```
<mesh>
  <uri>model://model_name/meshes/your_mesh.stl</uri>
  <scale>0.001 0.001 0.001</scale>
</mesh>
```

An alternative would be to rescale the mesh with an external editor.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [javi.galarza.s](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/23573/javi.galarza.s/) on 2020-02-17**:
That worked for me. just remember to write it down under every  part of the world code.
Thank you!